# Handle multiple parameter in SQL query using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, sql-like

I have a scenario where I need to exclude few thousands of email id with specific domain name.

My current query is

```
Select * from users where email NOT LIKE '%abc.com' 
                      AND email NOT LIKE '%efg.com'
                      AND email NOT LIKE '%xyz.com'
```

When I moved to python, I wrote a query like

```
MySQLcursor.execute (Select * from users where email NOT LIKE '%abc.com' 
                      AND email NOT LIKE '%efg.com'
                      AND email NOT LIKE '%xyz.com' )
```

Can I make a generic list of domains and exclude them?

What I tried is

```
list_of_domains = ('%%abc.com','%%xyz.com','%%efg.com')
MySQLcursor.execute (Select * from users where email NOT LIKE %(exclude_domain)s, {"exclude_domain":list_of_domains} )
```

It seems to work if there is only 1 value in list_of_domains. Because, when it unpacks the list it can only match "email Not Like" condition with 1 list of domain.

How can I make a generic query, so that if tomorrow, If I have new domains, I simply add that to list_of_domains and it works fine.

I am not sure if it is possible? Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like constructing queries using string interpolation and concatenation, but, assuming you cannot change the table schema and this is the query you have to do and you trust the source of the domain list, here is something to get you started:

```
domains = [...]

pattern = "email NOT LIKE '%{0}'"
conditions = " AND ".join([pattern.format(domain) for domain in domains])
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE " + conditions
```

Comment: It is actually appending single quotes to the value of conditions. So it becomes Select * from users where 'email NOT LIKE 'abc' AND email NOT LIKE 'def' ' . I am not using + conditions to append the query value, but I am using     query.execute("Select * from users where %s" ,(conditions))

Comment: @Neil you will have to use string concatenation (the + conditions) if you want to avoid the quotes being automatically put.